# How to add data in pre-existing document by searching for specific node in Firebase? (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is one document which is student profile with student data like course, username, status etc.
I want to add another node named uid in pre-existing document by searching for emailid

For example, In document containing emailid: "abc@gmail.com" I want to add uid:"111032" in that document containing emailid.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference studentRef = rootRef.child("STUDENT");

        lg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                username = un.getText().toString().trim();
                String password= pw.getText().toString().trim();
                lg.setText("Logging in...");
                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Welcome.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                                    final String current_user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                    //Save UID to database
                                    Query emailAddressQuery = studentRef.orderByChild("emailid").equalTo(username).limitToFirst(1);
                                    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                Map<String, Object> uidUpdate = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                                uidUpdate.put("uid", current_user_id);
                                                ds.getRef().updateChildren(uidUpdate);
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                            Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!

                                        }
                                    };
                                    emailAddressQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
                                    Intent i=new Intent(Welcome.this,Home.class);
                                   // i.putExtra("useremail", username);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    lg.setText("Log In");
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log In Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    lg.setText("Log in");
                                }

                                // ...
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```

The above code is actually is in sign in button which sign in the user get the uid and save it to that specific profile's info.[this is the image with more detailed information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGklI.png).

[As shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf0T9.png), I want to search by emailid (Shown in yellow) and add node called uid in that specific document.

OLD CODE :

```
username = un.getText().toString().trim();
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String current_user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("STUDENT").child(username);
                                    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                    updates.put("uid", current_user_id);
                                    ref.updateChildren(updates);
```

This code works but we have to pass the name of document while I want to pass data by child node in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference studentRef = rootRef.child("STUDENT");
Query emailAddressQuery = studentRef.orderByChild("emailid").equalTo("abc@gmail.com").limitToFirst(1);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map<String, Object> uidUpdate = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            uidUpdate.put("uid", uid);
            ds.getRef().updateChildren(uidUpdate).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "task is successful!");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
emailAddressQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result of this operation will be the update of the `uid` in the user object.

Comment: What if the abc@gmail.com is stored in a string? Can I pass that variable and will it work then?

Comment: Yes, it will for sure. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I tried the code its not working, not giving any errors and uid is also not there in the document

Comment: "not working" does **not** help me, help you. Have you used the debugger? Besides that, please edit your question and add the changed code. Please also add a screenshot of your database containing less black lines, to see where the issue might be.

Comment: Updated the post @Alex Mamo

Comment: In that case, please see my updated answer and tell me which one of those two log statements is printing something out in the logcat?

Comment: Sorry, I tried searching a lot in logcat but I didn't at least find task is successful message, can you tell me how can I find message or exception related to that specific function ? (as I am new at firebase and android studio hope you understand) @Alex Mamo

Comment: Filter the result in Android Studio by "TAG". Or change the code to something else, for example, "YourAppTAG" and filter it. Tell me if you get something.

Comment: I don't think that block is getting executed cause I put toast in both of the condition and when I executed it nothing is showing up (no toast is appearing ). Code is same as I have shown in my post. @Alex Mamo

Comment: Is `onComplete()` even triggered? Are you sure you have an internet connection?

Comment: Yes, of course, I have an internet connection, (I even tried fetching username by email and then passing that username to add uid , the same result nothing happens and you can't find anything in logcat) So what can I do?

Comment: Usually the `onComplete()` is not triggered when there is no internet connection available. Have you tried to hardcode the values? Like this `studentRef.orderByChild("emailid").equalTo("slater202020@gmail.com")`? Does it work this way?

Comment: No, its not working when it is hardcoded but the OLD CODE showed in the post works (when hardcoded)

Comment: If you try to add this line `Log.d("TAG", ds.getString("emailid"));` right after `uidUpdate.put("uid", uid);`, is it something printed out?

Comment: Says cannot resolve `getString ()` when added after `uidUpdate.put("uid", uid);`

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry. It should be `Log.d("TAG", ds.child("emailid").getValue(String.class));` Is it something printed out?

Comment: It does not show that TAG ,[this are the logcat logs when you click on the button](https://pastebin.com/yf95MhA5) if you just want to take a look (and I have already added `".indexOn": "emailid"` in my firebase rules)

Comment: I think that not even your `onDataChange` is triggered, as I cannot see any messages containing `TAG`.

Comment: So What else can we try now ?

Comment: Using my code, try to debug step by step and see where it gets wrong. Keep me also posted.